# Express: Asynchronous task inside request

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, express

I want to spawn an async/child task inside an express request handler.

Is the following understanding correct?

- Incoming request will start a promise chain. For an 'async/child' process, we can start a new promise.
- Rather than wait for callback of the promise above, we may send the response to the client, before the chain completes. <-- Linting tools will show you a warning here, as it is a common error, but can be intentional.
- The fact that a response has been sent, will not cause any promise that has been created without a callback (then or await) to be cancelled. This promise will still resolve or reject?

**Question:**

- Is the above description correct?
- If correct, when does response.close() or response.finish() event fire? Is it at the end of the promise chain or after the response was sent?

Comment: close will be called after the response was sent.

Comment: Did you mean an asynchronous task like calling a REST API or spawning a child process? And also Incoming request will start a promise chain? What did you mean by that?

Comment: @KiranMathewMohan Yes, I mean that if I want some async task to be triggered as part of the request, but don't need to wait for the outcome, I can just create a promise without `await` (or .then) and even if the response has been sent, the created promise will complete? (Therefore, it is not necessary to create a child process?)

Comment: If you just want to trigger some async task, you don't need to create a promise or anything, you can just call it and don't use await or then just like you mentioned. And below that you can use response.send() or response.json() or response.render() etc

Comment: "Express will wait for the whole promise chain to complete before considering the request done, despite that the response was sent." Why would it wait at all, because it is an async process and we aren't making it synchronous using promises or it's syntactic sugar async/await.

Comment: @KiranMathewMohan I mean the fact that the response has been sent will not cause any work that was started in the request handler to be cancelled? More importantly, exactly when does the response 'finish' event fire? This relates to cleaning up resources.

Comment: Yup true, since that task is asynchronous it is being worked on by a different worker of worker pool, AFAIK it won't get cancelled and will run to completion. I think response finish event should be fired when you have send a response from within the response handler, and since the task before that is asynchronous and non-blocking, performing resource cleanup might cause bad effects.